# Correct color profile and saving? Thumbnail creation?

Tags: images

I've never had this issue SRGB and everything looks good on screen, then on upload my reds turn like ... brownish pink. [image][image][image]

Edit: adding this just incase someone suggests monitor calibration or something. This is Octobers upload folder via FTP. Something is up with the thumbnail creation here.[image]

Comment: try "Save for Web", select RGB when saving out your images.

Comment: Save for web is outdated, but File > Export As, then saving the jpgs, may make a difference. No web image should be 240 ppi. Has anything on your site changed (any image plugins updated, etc.) or anything about the source images changed (taken on a different camera, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks Elaine ... ALL of the raw images that I shot have subtle color differences like that. So weird. 

I do need the correct profile and settings for the future though ... I tend to batch process things like this :/